# Allowing pages to be indexed for keywords with variable spelling

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way you can include content on a page but tell search engines to index that page with various spelling on keywords.
For example, if I'm writing a page about colour I'd like the search engine to find the page for searches for 'colour' and for 'color'. It would also be useful if this could be done for common spelling mistakes. Is there a way to do that using HTML of JavaScript?

Comment: Short answer is no there is not. Search engines are already aware of different locale spellings of words like colour/color

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that it was suggested to include spelling mistakes for searches of the wrong spelling. I don' t think that's a good idea but will search engines recongise spelling mistakes too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The bad news:

No, there isn't really a way to do that.

### The good news:

Most search engines (especially the ones that matter) are very good at recognizing alternate spellings and misspellings. Most will recommend an alternate search with the correctly spelled word, but even when the user doesn't click on it relevant links are usually still included in the search results for searches that contain a misspelling.

Historically this sort of thing was one of the intended uses for the meta keywords tag, but it should not be used these days. Most search engines completely ignore it. This is because some people used it to spam search results by packing it with popular keywords that were not related to the actual content of the page. [According to this](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2067564/how-to-use-html-meta-tags) Bing is the only one who still even looks at them, and that is just to detect spam.

Search engines have gotten very good at spotting and punishing attempts at keyword stuffing, so don't do it. Things like putting text on the same or similar colored background or hiding the text via JavaScript or CSS tricks will likely be detected and loose you search ranking instead of gaining it, or even [get your page banned](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-check-your-own-site/) from the search engine. ([Google is particularly good at this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353))

Just create pages with good content and it should be fairly findable.

Comment: You don't need to worry about me doing any 'black-hat' SEO techniques. I just found and 'blog post by one of my colleges that was talking about SEO and the spelling of optimisation had it using and s in some cases and a z and I thought we should be consistent but wasn't sure which spelling to use.